# How can I play an already uploaded video inside an Amazon S3 bucket? And how can I use the String Authentication on it?

Tags: files

I´m new with video module, and with Amazon S3.
I need a video (that I´ve **already uploaded** to an Amazon S3 bucket), to be able to be played inside my site. I don´t want to upload it again through Drupal.

This video needs to be **private**. I´ve read something about "**S3 Query String Authentication**" but didn´t get how to actually implement that in my site.

I´m not able to point to a video that´s already uploaded to a bucket. I can only upload through Drupal, or upload it to a folder inside my drupal installation. How can I just grab the video?

And Should I do that using string authentication? How can I avoid people that´s not logged in to see or link to the video? (I know that there´s no way to stop other people to copy your stuff, but I´ve read about hot links and would like to avoid that from happening if I can).

I need that video to be available for a long period of time for my users, I just don´t want them to post the link in other sites (and use my bandwith).

I´m pretty clueless. Please I would love some help if you can. Thanks!!!!
Rosamunda

Comment: Can you link to the module your using? This is very module specific support so it's hard w/out knowing exactly your setup. And this is Drupal 6 or 7? Always be sure to tag appropriately.

Comment: Thanks electblake. I´m using D6. Fortunately I´ve found a workaround... just not using this module at all. I was referring to the Video Module. I just used jwplayer directely to play the videos already stored in my S3 buckets. In fact, you can´t use this video as I thought (to point directely to S3). Here´s some more information: http://drupal.org/node/1317520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this, hoping I can help anyone else with the same problem.
If you're trying to play videos already uploaded to your S3 Amazon account, you won't find an appropriate Drupal Module to do so. ([see this](http://drupal.org/node/1317520)).
What I did is to get myself an Amazon Cloudfront account and protect the videos manually with an expiration date; then I pasted the video (using the player jwplayer), and I controlled the access to that node using any of the node access modules.

Comment: how did you end up referencing the S3 video in Drupal? Did you use the workaround described in #10? http://drupal.org/node/1317520#comment-5400750

Comment: No, sadly, I just uploaded the video to S3 and then put the link inside a Drupal node (inside a script that actually plays the video). But couldn´t do that in the way that I intended to.

Comment: yeah, I ended up doing the same ;-)